# g++: error: First: No such file or directory (running c++ on VScode 2021)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I installed MinGW and also updated path in environment variables. Also installed two extension on VScode 1) .codeRunner 2) c/c++
after this setup, i created a c++ file with name "firstprogram.cpp" in a folder and now this shows these error lines.

```
[Running] cd "f:\c++\" && g++ "First Program.cpp" -o First Program && "f:\c++\"First Program
    g++: error: First: No such file or directory
    g++: error: Program.cpp: No such file or directory
    g++: error: Program: No such file or directory
    g++: fatal error: no input files
    compilation terminated.
```

=> i'm using window10

although i followed this video from start to end:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvg4VtYEhKU&t=432s

Comment: Try `g++ "First Program.cpp"`

Comment: What is your response to the answer and comment above? If they're helpful, please upvote and accept the  the answer. If not, please comment why.

Answer (score 0):

It is searching for 2 files `First` and `Program.cpp`, but your file name is `First Program.cpp`, so you need to write them under quotes. `g++ "First Program.cpp" -o "First Program"`.

Whitespaces in filenames are evil. You should get rid of them if you can.